# How to split a list in R?

Tags: r

I have an R list where all of the values are in the first position (i.e. list[1]), while I want all the values to be spread evenly throughout the list (list[1] contains one value, list[2] contains the next, etc.). I have been trying unsuccessfully for a while to split the values one position into separate values (each value is a string of characters separated by spaces) but nothing has worked.

Below is an illustration of the sort of situation I am in.

Say "test" is the name of a list in R. Test is an object of length 1, and if you enter test[1] in the console, the output is thousands of values formatted like so:
[1] "value1" "value2" "value3" ... etc.

Now I want to somehow split the contents of list[1] so that each separated character string is in a separate position, so test[1] is "value1", test[2] is "value2", etc. I have looked around for and attempted many purported solutions to this sort of issue (recent example here: [List to integer or double in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814322/list-to-integer-or-double-in-r)) but nothing has worked for me so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: split elements of a list into sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420994/r-split-elements-of-a-list-into-sublists)

Comment: You can also access each element by `test[[i]][j]` where i is the list index and j is the index of the vector index at i list index i. If you only have one list element you can just `unlist(test)`

Comment: @at80 This is turning into a nightmare scenario for me. No matter what I try (and I have tried many, many, many approaches here), the same thing always results: if I try to select only the first element in this list, it invariably shows me EVERY element. This also held when I tried to use "do.call(c,test)" as you suggested.

Comment: `test1 <- as.list(test[[1]])` is what you are looking for. Now  try `test1[[1]]`

Comment: What does `class(test)` return?

Comment: I am losing my mind! @Onyambu I just tried what you suggested and yet again: when I enter "test1[1]", I get every value, and if I enter any other position in test1 (e.g. test1[2]), the output is "$<NA>
NULL".

Comment: @at80 class(test) returns "list".

Comment: can you tell us what `lengths(test)` is? also what is `class(test)`?

Comment: @Onyambu For every form of this list I have created (including test), the length is 1.

Comment: so you have a bunch of 1s?  what of `class(test)`?

Comment: in your comment you said that _Test is an object of length 1_ so how comes you have a bunch of 1's??

Comment: The length of each list is 1: length(test) returns 1. As noted above, class(test) returns "list". So it's a list of length 1 and I can't figure out how to split it.

Comment: But i asked for `lengths(test)` not `length(test)`

Comment: Are you saving the variable? `new_test <- do.call(c, test); new_test[2]`

Comment: @Onyambu sorry I didn't realize you meant lengths()--didn't even know that function existed separate from length() in R. Anyway, lengths(test) returns 1.

Comment: @at80 I tried your suggestion and yet again, newtest[2] returned $<NA>
NULL and all the thousands of strings were still combined in newtest[1].

Comment: well you do not have a vector, you have a string.  do `test1 <- strsplit(test[[1]], " ")` and then do `test2 <- as.list(unlist(test1))` then you can do `test2[[1]]`

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help without seeing sample data.

Comment: I can show sample data per the request of @at80. Below are the first ten rows of the dataset (which has thousands of rows in total):                                                   `1  107815
2   67608
3   21385
4   18053
5  231841
6   18400
7   72614
8   64654
9   12444
10 338370.` So if I now enter length(test), it returns 1, and if I enter test[1], every value is returned.

Comment: You did not read your data in correctly. The reason why every value is returned is because you have a string instead of a vector. You first need to split the string. Also since yu are dealing with lists, use `[[1]]` instead of `[1]`

Comment: Thank you to @Onyambu, your suggestion of test1 <- strsplit(test[[1]], " "), followed by test2 <- as.list(unlist(test1)) and test2[[1]], worked!

Comment: That is because you have a string. Please note that the problem you had and the topic did not go hand in hand, you need to be careful next time. Elaborate on what you have. Your issue was having a string

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way:

```
l1 <- list(l1 = round(rnorm(100, 0, 5), 0))
v <- unlist(l1)
l2 <- as.list(v)
```

`length` of `l1` is 1 and `length` of `l2` is 100. Is this what you are after?